# SSO SAML response in not getting in my Iframe

Tags: c#, iframe, knockout.js, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I am working on SSO login using Shibboleth. For the testing I am using SAML test. I have done with all Shibboleth Installation and IIS configuration. Now my application is navigating to SAML test login page through iframe because of some architectural design. After SSO login click its navigating to SAML SSO Login page once successfully login at SAML its not returning to my iframe page. Same is working on my sample web MVC Application. Please need help in same.

A] I am done with below points:

1. I am using KnockOut.Js with Asp.net MVC Application.
2. Shibboleth configuration needs Controller name as "Shibboleth" then and then only its navigating to Shibboleth site.
3. In my scenario I am calling any controller method from KnockOut.Js page due to observable its prefixing the controller name with main/app/Shibboleth/index instead of Shibboleth/Index. So call is not navigating to shibboleth site.
4. To bypass the knockout.Js flow I am using iframe so I can navigate to shibboleth login page with direct MVC flow and process response.
5. But when I am using Iframe then its successfully navigating to Shibboleth(SAML Test) site but once login its not returning to Shibboleth/Index page.
6. Normally its returning back to return URL but in case of iframe its not returning to return page.

B] I am expecting below points:

1. Any new flow which I can try?
2. Why its not returning to return url in case of iframe?
3. Best Approach to follow with shibboleth SSO login.